# pandas Difference between TimeStamp and creating new DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset as the following

```
u_id    request_day     time    request_time
4       2016-11-05      06:50   2016-11-05 06:50:30
4       2016-11-05      06:51   2016-11-05 06:51:55
4       2016-11-05      07:06   2016-11-05 07:06:38
4       2016-11-05      07:06   2016-11-05 07:06:44
4       2016-11-05      07:07   2016-11-05 07:07:32
4       2016-11-08      06:18   2016-11-08 06:18:03
4       2016-11-08      06:18   2016-11-08 06:18:10
4       2016-11-08      06:18   2016-11-08 06:18:55
5       2016-11-05      06:50   2016-11-05 06:50:30
5       2016-11-05      06:51   2016-11-05 06:51:55
5       2016-11-05      07:06   2016-11-05 07:06:38
5       2016-11-05      07:06   2016-11-05 07:06:44
5       2016-11-05      07:07   2016-11-05 07:07:32
5       2016-11-08      06:18   2016-11-08 06:18:03
5       2016-11-08      06:18   2016-11-08 06:18:10
5       2016-11-08      06:18   2016-11-08 06:18:55
```

for each u_id, request_day, I want the total time spent.
for eg : 
u_id: 4, request day: 2016-11-05, you find the difference between the time, if the time difference is less 2 mins, is a valid difference. not more than 2 minutes.

a new dataFrame is suppose to be formed

```
u_id    request_day     time_spent
4       2016-11-05      2:19       [(6:50:30 - 6:51:55) + <(6:51:55 - 7:06:38)> + (07:06:38 - 07:06:44) + (07:06:44 - 07:07:32)]
```

ignore the time difference in the list which has < time >, as the difference is greater than two minutes.

should I do this by using for loop for each u_id and a loop for each request_day.

or is there a different approach for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following approach:

```
# change to datetime format if it isn't already
df.request_time = pd.to_datetime(df.request_time)

# group by u_id anf request_date and find the difference between the current and next row
time_diff = df.groupby(['u_id', 'request_day']).apply(lambda x: x.request_time.diff())

# select all data where the time_diff < 2 minutes and sum
time_diff[time_diff < pd.Timedelta('2M')].groupby(['u_id', 'request_day']).sum()
```

Output:

```
u_id  request_day
4     2016-11-05    00:02:19
      2016-11-08    00:00:52
5     2016-11-05    00:02:19
      2016-11-08    00:00:52
Name: request_time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

> EDIT: Or you can use the following one liner operation:

```
df.groupby(['u_id', 'request_day']).apply(lambda x: x.request_time.diff().where(
    x.request_time.diff() < pd.Timedelta('2M')
).sum())
```